# Find a line intersecting a specific line and who is parallel to a specific plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a line $L_1$ that goes through point $(1,-2,-1)$.

$L_1$ is parallel to the plane $x+3y-z=0$

$L_1$ is intersecting line $L_2$ where $L_2$ is given by: 
$$L_2 = \begin{cases} x= 1+t \\ y=2-t \\ z=3+2t \end{cases}$$

Find an equation for $L_1$.

I believe I've tried everthing I can do but I get stuck. Here is my attempt.

We know that $L_1$ can be written as: 
$$L_1 = \begin{cases} x= 1+as \\ y=-2 +bs \\ z=-1+cs \end{cases}$$
where s is the parameter. So I need to find an $(a,b,c)$ that satisfies the above conditions.

So the vector $(a,b,c)$ should satisfy the following if it is parallel to the plane:
$$a+3b-c = 0$$

And we need to find a $(a,b,c)$ that satisfies: 
$$1+as-1+t=0$$
$$-2+bs-2+t=0$$
$$-1+cs-3-2t=0$$
which is equivalent to: 
$$as-t+0=0$$
$$bs+t-4=0$$
$$cs-2t-4=0$$

I attempt to solve the following system of equations and get 
$$3a+b-c=0$$.

Combining this from what I got above means that 
$$3a+b-c=0=a+3b-c=$$
$$a=b$$

This is the only information I can scramble out of it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to find the point in $L_2$ that $L_1$ intersects.  What is the distance of $L_1$ from the plane?  For what value of $t$ is $L_2$ the correct distance from the plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the distance of (1,-2,-1) from the plane $x + 3y - z = 0$?

plug the points into $x + 3y - z = d$ and solve for $d.$

All points on L_1 will have this same $d.$

$1(1) + 3(-2)-1(-1) = -4$

Now we plug the values of $L_2$ into the equation of the plane hoding $d$ constant.

$1(1+t) + 3(2-t) -(3+2t) = -4$
and solve for t:
$-4t = -8, t = 2$

$L_1$ intersects the point $(3,0,7)$

Now you know two points that $L_1$ goes through.

$L_1 = (1 + 2s, -2 + 2s, -1+8s)$

And verify that $(2,2,8)\cdot(1,3,-1) = 0$